# How to show a modal view with an animation iOS?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I did a code to popup a modal view in iOS like following,

```
-(void)customizeAction:(id)sender{
    UIView *modalView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextureView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
    [self.view addSubview:modalView];
}
```

But I need to pop this up with an animation(pop it from the bottom). Is there any possible way to do it??

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this , You use this code

```
UIView *modalView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TextureView" owner:self options:nil] objectAtIndex:0];
[modalView setFrame:CGRectMake(0, CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetWidth(self.view.bounds), CGRectGetHeight(self.view.bounds))];
[self.view addSubview:modalView];
[UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
    CGRect currentRect = modalView.frame;
    currentRect.origin.y = 0;
    [modalView setAlpha:1];
    [modalView setFrame:currentRect];
    [self.view bringSubviewToFront:modalView];
}];
```

On button click add the view below the screen rect and animate it to top using `UIView`'s animation block.

And to pop

```
- (void)popModalView
{

    [UIView animateWithDuration:1 animations:^{
        CGRect currentRect = modalView.frame;
        currentRect.origin.y = self.view.frame.size.width/2;
        [modalView setAlpha:0.5];
        [modalView setFrame:currentRect];
        [modalView removeFromSuperview];
    }];
}
```

You need to declare `modalView` globally.

Hope this helps.

Comment: it works. and also how can I pop this modal view half of the screen?

Comment: Can you help me with pop please? I tried this pop code and it removes the view immediately. I need it look like dismiss of modal view, thanks in advance.

Comment: increase the animation duration @Avi